# ASP.Net - My gridview is too tall when it has very few rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using a `GridView`.

If my SQL Statement only returns one row, my gridview has one single row that is too tall.

If my SQL Statement returns only a few rows, my gridview has a few rows that are each too tall, but not nearly as tall as when only one row is returned.

If my SQL Statement returns a lot of rows, they are more normal-sized and there is no problem.

Why might my Gridview Rows change height like this based upon the quantity of rows returned?

Comment: Can you please ask your question in a completely different way?

Comment: What is the question??.Please reformat.

Comment: If you have fixed the height and width of your gridview remove it and try again. or better to reformat your question.

Comment: Please post your gridview markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `Height` attribute and value from your Gridview.

**Example**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="505px" ...
```

**Should be**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ...
```

Alternatively, remove the CSSClass from your gridview (or remove `height` from the CSS Class)

**References**

- [WebControl.Height MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.height.aspx)
- [Gridview MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx)
- [Similar Problem](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=523001)